# Alexa simulator shows black screen

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

while testing OpenURL command no page is opened in Alexa simulator.Can someone help me on this ?.

{
"type": "OpenURL",
"source": "https://www.amazon.com/",
"onFail": {
"type": "SetValue",
"componentId": "errorText",
"property": "text",
"value": "Unable to open Amazon.com (${event.source.value})"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

The simulator doesn't support it.

[Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-standard-commands.html#open_url_command)

> Not all devices support opening a URL. If the device does not support opening URLs, the command is ignored and it does not run onFail commands. Check the value of the allowOpenURL in the data-binding context to determine if OpenURL is supported on the device.

**Check the value of the allowOpenURL in the data-binding context to determine if OpenURL is supported on the device.**